# Prevent system sleep/shutdown/reboot in a bash script

Tags: linux, macos, bash

By execution of a bash script which takes a long time to run I will prevent a manual executed system sleep/shutdown/reboot. It would be nice if the logged on user will get a message but it´s not necessary. Normally I´m looking for a working solution for OS X but for Linux would also be nice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Temporarily prevent linux from shutting down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322254/temporarily-prevent-linux-from-shutting-down)

Comment: On OS X, you can use the [`caffeinate` command](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/caffeinate.8.html) to prevent sleep.

Comment: @rpax Well it sounds like my question but there are no accepted answer :(.

Comment: @KenThomases I know caffeinate but I don´t know if it works with an manual initiated sleep/reboot/shutdown

Comment: From the man page, it looks like the `-s` option can prevent a manual initiated sleep. Don't know about reboot or shutdown.

Comment: @KenThomases: If your write your solutions as an answer I could accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On OS X, you can use the [`caffeinate -s /path/to/your/script`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/caffeinate.8.html) command to prevent sleep while your script runs.